# Where does the Master equation for the derivation of the Fokker-Planck equation come from?

Tags: biophysics, diffusion, stochastic-processes

I'm participating in an introductory course for biophysics. We briefly discussed the derivation of the [Fokker-Planck equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fokker%E2%80%93Planck_equation) and used the so-called Master equation as a starting point.

$$
\frac{\partial P(x)}{\partial t}=\int \mathrm{d}x'\left[W\left(x\vert x'\right)P\left(x'\right)-W\left(x'\vert x\right)P\left(x\right)\right]
$$

It seems like the term 'Master equation' simply describes a set of equations which describe the time evolution of a probabilistic system. But why do we use this specific Master equation for the derivation of the Fokker-Planck equation and how was it found?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The master equation is summarized in words as follows:

> The rate of change of the probability of one state occurring is equal to the rate at which transitions occur *into* that state minus the rate at which transitions occur *out* of that state.

This is one of those situations where it's useful to think of probability as a fluid: the change in the height of a fluid in a box is equal to the flow *into* the box minus the flow *out* of the box.

So, to proceed with the derivation, let's start with the definition of $W(x|x')$. The quantity $W(x|x')$ is the rate at which the system transitions to state $x$ *given that* it's in state $x'$. This means that the rate at which the system transitions from $x'$ to $x$ is equal to the probability $P(x')$ that it's in state $x'$ in the first place, multiplied by the transition rate $W(x|x')$ from $x'$ to $x$; in other words, the transition rate from $x'$ to $x$ is given by $W(x|x')P(x')$.

The *total* transition rate from *any other state* into $x$ is given by the sum of the transition rates for all possible transitions. For systems with a discrete set of states $S$, the total transition rate into $x$ is given by $\sum_{x'\in S}W(x|x')P(x')$. It's easy to extend this to a system with a continuous set of states: just replace the sum with an integral over the entire state space, so the total transition rate into $x$ is given by $\int W(x|x')P(x')dx'$.

Using basically the same argument, the transition rate from $x$ to $x'$ is given by $W(x'|x)P(x)$ (the probability that the system is in state $x$ in the first place, multpilied by the transition rate from $x$ to $x'$ given that the system is in state $x$). Summing/integrating over all possible transitions *out* of state $x$, we have that the total transition rate from $x$ to *any other state* is given by $\int W(x'|x)P(x)dx'$.

Now that we have the total transition rate into $x$ and the total transition rate out of $x$, to get the total change in probability density, we just subtract the two (see the fluid analogy: we're saying "change in quantity = flow in - flow out), so that

$$\frac{\partial P(x)}{\partial t}=\int W(x|x')P(x') - W(x'|x)P(x)\;dx'$$

which is precisely the master equation.

Comment: Okay, I now understand the meaning of the Master equation and its derivation, thanks! But what is the link between this (very abstract) formula and the physical implications of the Fokker-Planck equation, in which we suddenly can identify drift and diffusion? Did somebody just simplify the master equation with the Kramers-Moyal expansion and saw that the result is able to describe the movements of particles?

Comment: @JoKli Yes, the Fokker-Planck equation is the second-order truncation of the master equation (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kramers%E2%80%93Moyal_expansion).

Comment: Sure, we did the calculations in the lecture and I understand the mathematical derivation. However, I don't understand how we can start at an equation which describes an abstract mathematical consideration and then arrive at the Fokker-Planck equation which can describe Brownian motion. There must be some reason why we start at this master equation.

Comment: Couldn't that equation be derived from Liouville's equation in phase space? $$\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t} = \{\rho, \, H \} = \frac{\partial \rho}{\partial x^k} \, \frac{\partial H}{\partial p_k} - \frac{\partial H}{\partial x^k} \, \frac{\partial \rho}{\partial p_k}.$$

Comment: I just found that the master equation is the [Chapman-Kolmogorow equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chapman%E2%80%93Kolmogorov_equation) which describes Markov-chains. So I guess the underlying assumption is, that Brownian motion can be considered as a Markov process and with that assumption we start at the master equation and then derive the FPE.